# Handling JSON response with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, post, oauth-2.0, box-api

There are tons of questions related to mine, but after spending several hours poring over different answers and experimenting on my own, I still can't solve my problem!

I'm using the OAuth 2.0 protocol to gain access to Box's API.  So far I've been able to retrieve an authorization code, and right now I am trying to trade it for an access code.  Everything seems to be working fine so far: after I make a POST request to Box, I get redirected to https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/token and receive a JSON response that I have no idea how to deal with.

I've tried using JQuery's $.get and $.parseJSON functions but I have no idea how I'm supposed to structure the code at all or if I'm approaching this the right way in the first place.

Here is the function I'm using to POST:

```
function post_to_url(path, params) {

    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", "post");
    form.setAttribute("action", 'https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/token');

    for(var key in params) {
        if(params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "text");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
            hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);

            form.appendChild(hiddenField);
         }
    }

    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
}
```

And when I call it, I get redirected to https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/token and my browser shows the following string:

```
{"access_token":"H97GnkuWCRUxxx"expires_in":3600,"refresh_token":"cIJyyyyym1aSuNFmmC2PgTtiP2xfXm0dCmzzzz,"token_type":"bearer"}
```

I truly appreciate any help I can get, thanks so much!

Comment: jsonp probably? is inside of a function? you also can access as 
var object = _json_response_; object["access_token"] or object.access_token. If it is a JSONP there is a specific function in jquery for it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need jquery to do this, it's very simple in fact.

```
var json = JSON.parse(the returned json var);
```

Then you can handle it like this:

```
json.access_token; //this would be the access token
```

Here is the code I use for POST/GET requests:

```
    var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST','url', true);//the true bool makes it async
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); //this url encodes the request (this is for if you have special values such as spaces and symbols)
    xhr.send(information to send goes here);
    xhr.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if(xhr.readyState===4)
        {
            if(xhr.status===200)
            {
                var json = xhr.responseText;
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  My problem is that I don't know how to collect the json var.  When I make the POST request I get redirected to a website as shown here: http://i.imgur.com/W9Q1roF.png.  At this point, any code I write past the POST request isn't triggered.  I'm guessing there has to be a way to encapsulate the POST request in a variable to store the JSON object but I'm not sure how.  Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @user2066880 I added an example post request

Comment: @user2066880 The way you're doing it will bring you to another page, the way I do it is via an ajax request.

Comment: I've tried a similar solution to this and I've been getting a cross-domain error "XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/token. Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  I haven't been able to resolve it and that's why I've been using that roundabout way of making the POST request.  Thanks again for the help

Comment: I have to run to class for a bit, but I'll add you as soon as I get back and if you could help me at your convenience that would be great.  Thanks so much for the help.